# How to Login via RealVNC Connect first time on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, login, vnc

I have a new Raspberry Pi and am attempting to setup headless operation using the recommended RealVNC.  The server is operating fine (I see the verification information) and I have set up the VNC Viewer on my W10 machine.  I'm feeling dumb because I cannot login.  I'm told:

Enter VNC Server credentials
(Hint: NOT your RealVNC account details)

It then wants Username and Password.

I've tried the RPI username and password as well as RealVNC credentials, but they don't work.

- Where would I find the username they're looking for?
- What password are they looking for?

---

Here's what I think you wanted from the log file

<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.205Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: AbModuleHosted: AddressBook entered foreground, resuming syncing
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.467Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: LaunchProcess: Launching "C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe" -child "RPI JEM" -hash bfcada60a03a48e8c16cadd75659db3177867cbb47275bb6ce4d91273f129460 -sid S-1-5-21-2674226592-144481052-2452000374-1001 RealVNC.James.vncviewer.vncpipehelper.804020189
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.578Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: AbModuleHosted: AddressBook entered background, pausing syncing
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000002,SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion,rw) (sam=20019) = 1e4
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Eula
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable MiscParams
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable MsgBoxMui
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable ConnectingDlg
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable UserPasswdDlgAb
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable InteractiveTextDlgMui
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable SecurityDlgMui
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable IdStore
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable SecVerify
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable UserPasswd
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable InteractiveText
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable RsaKeyEnt
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable F8Menu
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Toolbar
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable KeepAlive
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable ReconnectorOverlay
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable InfoDlgEnt
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable AboutDlg
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable BadVersion
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable FullScreen
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable ScaleToFit
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Audio
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable AuditEventsMgr
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Proxy
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable TcpConnect
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable UdpConnect
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Zeroconf
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Hosted
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable AbHosted
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable AutoSignIn
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable OnDemand
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable AbOnDemand
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable OptionsDlg
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable EntCommon
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable CloseAlertMsgBox
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable SelectDesktop
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable SecurityArd
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable SecurityNoneCiphers
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable SecurityRA4
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable SecurityRA2
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable RelPtr
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Sso
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable PubkeyAuth
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Print
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Ft
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable FileOps
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable VirtualMedia
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Chat
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Chat2
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable CtrlComms
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable ViewOnlyAlias
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable MiscAliases
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable ListenMode
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable FileOptions
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable PasswdFile
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Elevate
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Reboot
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: TestFeaturesEnableKey: Enabled 0
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable RecordInputs (failed)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable PlayInputs (failed)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable JumpList
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable WinMisc
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.830Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable ImExCmdLine
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Thumb
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable SplashDlg
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable AbAnalytics
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Analytics
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable HostedAnalytics
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable FopsAnalytics
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable Chat2Analytics
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Feature: Enable ImportOldConfig
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000002,Software\RealVNC\AllUsers\vncviewer,rw) (sam=20019) = 80
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ConfigParameter: set EulaAccepted(string) to true, priority 10
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000001,Software,rw) (sam=f003f) = 80
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(80,RealVNC,rw) (sam=f003f) = 1dc
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(1dc,vncviewer,rw) (sam=f003f) = 80
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: Settings already exist
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000001,Software\RealVNC\vncviewer,rw) (sam=20019) = 1e4
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000001,Software,rw) (sam=f003f) = 1e4
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(1e4,RealVNC,rw) (sam=f003f) = 80
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(80,vncviewer,rw) (sam=f003f) = 1e4
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000001,Software\RealVNC\vncviewer,rw) (sam=20019) = 80
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ConfigParameter: set EnableAnalytics(bool) to 1, priority 10
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ConfigParameter: set Log(string) to *:file:100, priority 10
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ConfigParameter: set _AnlClientId(string) to 6a8559f4-7cac-4295-b926-f3b37b7a3927, priority 10
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ConfigParameter: set _AnlInclRate(string) to 0.0025, priority 10
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ConfigParameter: set _AnlSelected(bool) to 0, priority 10
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ConfigParameter: set _SplashVer(int) to 1, priority 10
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000001,Software\RealVNC\vncviewer,rw) (sam=20019) = 80
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000001,Software,rw) (sam=f003f) = 254
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(254,RealVNC,rw) (sam=f003f) = 1dc
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(1dc,vncviewer,rw) (sam=f003f) = 254
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(254,KnownHosts,rw) (sam=f003f) = 1dc
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CModuleHosted: CloudConfig.pkg file not found
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CModuleHosted: Getting CloudConfig.pkg from built-in resource
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: VendorConfig: Reading VendorConfig from configData
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CModuleHosted: Using business identifier d69feb8f-ca91-442a-a72b-02b0546db86a
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Threading: created   PromptForFetchDir 63b4
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Threading: created   IconThread 606c
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Threading: started   IconThread 606c
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000001,Software,rw) (sam=f003f) = 45c
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(45c,RealVNC,rw) (sam=f003f) = 36c
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(36c,vncviewer,rw) (sam=f003f) = 45c
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(45c,VirtualMedia,rw) (sam=f003f) = 36c
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CModuleCtrlComms: Listening on RealVNC.James.vncviewer.CtrlComms.14172
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Threading: created   ClipboardThread 1180
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Threading: started   ClipboardThread 1180
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ProxySettings: WinHTTP user's IE config says auto-detect
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Threading: created   IpResolveThread 2cc4
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpConnector: Starting fallback timer (750 ms)
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CSession: Connecting to raspberrypi (Chooser for Direct UDP/Direct TCP via proxy settings)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.831Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Threading: started   IpResolveThread 2cc4
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.837Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: HostedBootstrapInfo: Trying https://hb-c.services.vnc.com:443/bootstrap/1.2/configuration/3...
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.837Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: BootstrapRequest: Serving Bootstrap response from cache
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.837Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: HostedBootstrapInfo: Trying https://hb-c.services.vnc.com:443/bootstrap/1.2/configuration/3...
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.837Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: BootstrapRequest: Serving Bootstrap response from cache
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.837Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000001,Software,rw) (sam=f003f) = 558
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.837Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(558,RealVNC,rw) (sam=f003f) = 554
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.837Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(554,vncviewer,rw) (sam=f003f) = 558
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.838Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ClipboardListener: Registered via AddClipboardFormatListener
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.838Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Clipboard: opening clipboard
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.842Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Clipboard: closed clipboard
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.874Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolver: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690:b122:cb02:1133:ac11]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.874Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolver: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690::cb59]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.874Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolver: Resolved 10.0.0.68::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.874Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolverIpc: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690:b122:cb02:1133:ac11]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.874Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolverIpc: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690::cb59]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.874Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolverIpc: Resolved 10.0.0.68::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.874Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpAddrConnector: Trying UDP to [2601:43:102:d690:b122:cb02:1133:ac11]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.874Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using receive buffer size of 1500 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.874Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using send buffer size of 750 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.885Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpAddrConnector: Trying UDP to [2601:43:102:d690::cb59]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.885Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using receive buffer size of 1500 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.885Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using send buffer size of 750 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.896Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpAddrConnector: Trying UDP to 10.0.0.68::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.896Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using receive buffer size of 1500 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:04.896Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using send buffer size of 750 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:05.578Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpConnector: UDP not connected after 750ms, trying Direct TCP via proxy settings fallback
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:05.581Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ProxySettings: Proxy auto-discovery did not find PAC script
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:05.581Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ProxySettings: WinHTTP user's IE config says connect directly
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:05.581Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ProxyFetcherConnector: Using direct connection
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.839Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolver: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690:b122:cb02:1133:ac11]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.839Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolver: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690::cb59]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.839Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolver: Resolved 10.0.0.68::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.839Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolverIpc: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690:b122:cb02:1133:ac11]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.839Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolverIpc: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690::cb59]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.839Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolverIpc: Resolved 10.0.0.68::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.839Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: TcpAddrConnector: Trying TCP to [2601:43:102:d690:b122:cb02:1133:ac11]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.864Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpConnector: Connected via Direct TCP (took 3013ms)
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.864Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CSession: Beginning RFB connection to raspberrypi::5900 (TCP)
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.864Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CSession: Encryption set to 'Server'
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.899Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CConnection: reading protocol version
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.899Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CConnection: Server supports RFB protocol version 5.0
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.899Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CConnection: Using RFB protocol version 5.0
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.899Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Requesting cipher suite RA4_128 [0x0202]
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.899Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Requesting cipher suite RA4b_256 [0x0b03]
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.899Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Requesting cipher suite RA4_256 [0x0303]
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.899Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Requesting cipher suite RA4ne_128 [0x0204]
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.899Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: RfbConnection: Peer supports sync, KeepAlive enabled
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.942Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Server selected cipher suite RA4_128 [0x0202] (algorithms: RSA-OAEP, ECDHE-Curve25519, SHA-256, AES-GCM-128)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.942Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: open(80000001,Software,rw) (sam=f003f) = 564
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.942Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(564,RealVNC,rw) (sam=f003f) = 558
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.942Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: Registry: create(558,vncviewer,rw) (sam=f003f) = 564
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.942Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CipherRA4: Local private key has 2048 bits
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.942Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CipherRA4: Remote public key has 2048 bits
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.994Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CipherCore: Established unauthenticated shared secret, session id = 3ae01ff6f1bd7018b2d4566c2aa0680f93cdf2ff504ee769ac1a497cb280303f
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:07.994Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CipherCore: Sending key establishment notification - changing outgoing encryption (algorithm: AES-GCM-128)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:08.054Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CipherCore: Received key establishment notification - changing incoming encryption (algorithm: AES-GCM-128)
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:08.054Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CipherCore: Established authentication for shared secret, peer id = 51-31-ca-94-56-ca-76-eb
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:08.186Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Server offered authentication method UserPasswd(1) [required=1]
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:08.186Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Looking for auth method SingleSignOn(4)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:08.186Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Looking for auth method PublicKey(3)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:08.186Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Looking for auth method UserPasswd(1)
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:08.186Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CProtoPostV4: Choosing authentication method UserPasswd(1)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:25.376Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ConfigParameter: set UserName(string) to James, priority 20
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:26.932Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CConnection: close: [AuthFailure] Either the username was not recognised, or the password was incorrect
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:26.932Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SctpIo: shutdown 000001E228FBE000, flush false (tellHandler false)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:26.932Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SctpIo: shutdown 000001E229010330, flush false (tellHandler false)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:26.932Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SctpIo: shutdown 000001E228FBE890, flush false (tellHandler false)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:26.932Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: FdIo: shutdown 000001E228FC9580 (fd=1352), flush true (tellHandler true)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:26.991Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SctpIo: shutdown complete 000001E228FBE000
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:26.991Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SctpIo: shutdown complete 000001E229010330
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:26.991Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SctpIo: shutdown complete 000001E228FBE890
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:26.991Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: FdIo: shutdown complete 000001E228FC9580 (fd=1352)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.126Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ProxySettings: WinHTTP user's IE config says auto-detect
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.126Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpConnector: Starting fallback timer (100 ms)
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.126Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CSession: Connecting to raspberrypi (Chooser for Direct UDP/Direct TCP via proxy settings)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.163Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolver: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690:b122:cb02:1133:ac11]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.163Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolver: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690::cb59]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.163Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolver: Resolved 10.0.0.68::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.163Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolverIpc: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690:b122:cb02:1133:ac11]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.163Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolverIpc: Resolved [2601:43:102:d690::cb59]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.163Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: IpResolverIpc: Resolved 10.0.0.68::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.163Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpAddrConnector: Trying UDP to [2601:43:102:d690:b122:cb02:1133:ac11]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.163Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using receive buffer size of 1500 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.163Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using send buffer size of 750 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.174Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpAddrConnector: Trying UDP to [2601:43:102:d690::cb59]::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.174Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using receive buffer size of 1500 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.174Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using send buffer size of 750 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.184Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpAddrConnector: Trying UDP to 10.0.0.68::5900
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.184Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using receive buffer size of 1500 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.184Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SocketUtil: Using send buffer size of 750 KiB
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.226Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: UdpConnector: UDP not connected after 100ms, trying Direct TCP via proxy settings fallback
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.227Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ProxySettings: Proxy auto-discovery did not find PAC script
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.227Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ProxySettings: WinHTTP user's IE config says connect directly
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:33.227Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: ProxyFetcherConnector: Using direct connection
<14> 2019-11-02T00:02:34.721Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: CConnection: close: [Cancelled] Cancelled
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:34.721Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SctpIo: shutdown 000001E228FBE000, flush false (tellHandler false)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:34.721Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SctpIo: shutdown 000001E228FBE890, flush false (tellHandler false)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:34.721Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Child: 14172: SctpIo: shutdown 000001E2290FDA80, flush false (tellHandler false)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:34.741Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: AbModuleHosted: AddressBook entered foreground, resuming syncing
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:34.751Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: Ipc: AbChild: End of stream from OS handle
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:34.751Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: HandleIo: shutdown 0000000000000568, flush 0 (tellHandler 0)
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:34.751Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: HandleIo: immediate shutdown 0000000000000568
<15> 2019-11-02T00:02:35.946Z JEM-HOME vncviewer[26284]: AbModuleHosted: AddressBook entered background, pausing syncing

Comment: Can you set your _VNC Viewer_ up on your _MicroSoft_ _Windows_ **10** Operating System Software Installation so that it gets to write some Log Files? Can you edit your question so that we can see what it is writing in them during your Login Procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  As the prompt indicated, it wanted my RPI Raspian login info.  I thought I'd tried it in my many login attempts, but apparently not.  This time it worked fine.
Sorry for the newbie floundering